# Add one day to hours

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$time = new DateTime('today 6 PM');
$now = new DateTime('now');
// check if current time is past 6 PM
if ($now > $time) {
     $time = new DateTime('Next Saturday 6 PM');
}

$diff = $time->diff($now);    
echo $diff->format("%h hours %i minutes remaining");
```

and want to add to the hours the days until the next Saturday, and that to every Saturday, so If we reach one it should automaticlly start itfrom beginning

Comment: `and want to add to the hours the days until the next Saturday, and that to every Saturday, so If we reach one it should automaticlly start itfrom beginning` - What do you mean? Please explain in detail what you're trying to accomplish, and include expected output in the question.

Comment: he wants some one to write a code for him

Comment: `$time = new DateTime('Next Saturday 6 PM');` - This is just awesome!

Comment: I mean the Days to 'Next Saturday 6 PM'  the script above shows only The time to 6 pm but @Amal Murali now you have days to Saturday. so I don't wan to show the daylike "$d and %h hours %i minutes remaining". I want to make it simple and add the days automaticlly to the hours... so if there are from now 6 or 5 or 4 day it should be added to "$h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get each days, hours, and minutes separately:

```
$diff = $time->diff($now); 
$days = $diff->format("%a");
$hours = $diff->format("%h");
$minutes = $diff->format("%i");
$total_hours = $days * 24 + $hours; //figure out the total hours
echo "$total_hours hours $minutes minutes remaining";
```

Comment: "You need to get each days, hours, and minutes separately:" thats it thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 $plusSix = date('Y-m-d' , strtotime('+6 hours' , time())); // to add 6 hours
```

to check the day I think:

```
$dayNumber = date('w' , strtotime('2012-01-01'));
```

Comment: The OP is already using `DateTime` class, so I do not see the need for `strtotime()` here. Also, this does not answer the original question (a poorly phrased one at that) that was asked.

Comment: @AmalMurali `strtotime` does support stuff like `+2 days`, `next sunday` etc without making headache.

Comment: @dognose: So what? `DateTime` handles it just fine. For example: `$now = $now->modify('+2 day');`.

Comment: then its just `perference` whether to use a object or functional approach. I'd prefer `strtotime`. (but because i usually continue with the timestamp)

Comment: $now = $now->modify('+2 day'); don't work already I tried it befor

Comment: @dognose so which way should i take now

Comment: go with whatever is easier to understand and use for you

Comment: @dognose so make a new script? or is there anything to modifiy